# syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash, shell-script

Sou novato e estou com problemas com o script abaixo:

```
echo "Enter an A, B or C"
read letter

if [[ $letter == "A" || $letter == "a" ]];
then
    echo  "this is A"
elif
    [[ $input == "B" || $input == "b" ];
then
    echo "this is B"
elif
   [ $input == "C" || $input == "c" ];
    echo "this is C"
set -x
fi
```

> erro: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Comment: Por quê o último `elif` não tem um `then`?

Comment: falta o `then` no último `elif` ou substitua pelo `else`